# Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on sql select statment

Tags: php, sql

```
 $results = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT sound_link_droos.linkname, sound_link_droos.linknote, sound_link_droos.linkurl, sound_link_droos.date, sound_link_droos.rating, sund_cat_droos.catname, sound_cat_droos.catpic 
                              FROM sound_link_droos
                             INNER JOIN sound_cat_droos
                             ON sound_link_droos.catid=sound_cat_droos.catid
                             where sound_link_droos.accept='1'
                             ORDER BY linkid DESC
                             LIMIT ?, ?");

    $results->bind_param("dd", $position, $item_per_page); 
$results->execute(); //Execute prepared Query
$results->bind_result($linkname, $linknote, $linkurl, $date, $rating, $catname, $catpic); //bind variables to prepared statement

//output results from database
while($results->fetch()){ //fetch values
    echo '<li>'.$linkid.') <strong>'.$linkname.'  </strong> : '.$linknote.' : '.$catname.' </li>';
```

Please help me.. I am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in
>   /home4/d5z2u4l4/public_html/aljannroad.com/auto_load/fetch_pages.php
>   on line 21

Comment: Your query failed. Use error reporting to see why.. Maybe `linkid` is in both tables? http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: linkid is not in both tables.

Comment: What did the error reporting tell you?